# SharePoint sandboxed solution call javascript function from back end

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sandbox-solution, codebehind

I have created a sandboxed solution for SharePoint 2013 which contains sandboxed visual webpart.

I need to call JavaScript function from back end. How can I accomplish this requirement? How can we load the .aspx page and where will I write the code behind so that I can get the variables passed using JavaScript function.

I have to perform some action on server side before calling JavaScript function, so I have to make call from back end. I am not able to do it using

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "resultSetFunction();", true);.
```

Comment: There's a need (or reason) for call javascript function from back end instead make all the _logic_ in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

use variable `this`

`this.Page.ClientScript`...

Make sure u have referred JS file in the visual webpart.

Comment: I have tried it with this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "resultSetFunction();", true); and added alert on document.ready. I am able to get alert but Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "resultSetFunction();", true); is not working... Can you plz give any other solution. Thanks for this one.

Comment: Use Registerclientscript instead of RegisterStartupScript

Comment: it seems you are calling "resultSetFunction()" function in the script which i guess u have written in JS file, if it is the case this will not work. Because you are running the register script function on serverside and pointing to client side script.

Comment: ohh...Ok.I am registering my script on RenderControl() method then what should I write on back end to call any function of that script file ?

Comment: You have register the JS function on Server side - we do this generally only for the samll function. You have t revise your business logic to implement. But the proposed comments solves your question.

Comment: This is what I have done in webpart.My js file
$(function () {
    alert("hi");
});
function resultSet() {
    alert("welcome");
}
my .aspx page:
script type="text/javascript" src="/Style Library/JS/javascript/myjs.js"/script
my .cs page:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myjs", "resultSet();", true);
}
On page load I am able to get "hi" but not able to get "Welcome". What should I write at the place of this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myjs", "resultSet();", true); in my cs file.

Comment: You need to write the script function of resultset as the string variable in cs file and call like this in the following example:

Comment: string script = String.Concat("<script type='text/javascript\'>$('#basicModal').dialog({ " +
        "width: 300" +
        "});</script>");
   // Gets the executing web page
   Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

   // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't allready on the Page
   if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("jdlg"))
    {
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, typeof(JavaScriptLayer), "jdlg", script, false);
    }

Comment: I suggest put the _source code_ both in the answer and question; it's hard to read.